# Weird Backtick in column name

Tags: mysql

Unfortunately some dev has added an unusual column name to a table which is proving difficult to select, eventually will get the column renamed but by the time it goes through the normal ticking and approval process, well it will be a while

The column is called:  -a.`GBPAmt`   ( so -a. then backticks `GBPAmt` )

Tried a variety of different things and there is probably an easy way around it but in essence what to have a simple query that does:

```
select -a.`GBPAmt` from table
```

Thanks

Comment: @OP: can you generate result for `show create table table_name` and add to your posting here

Comment: simple use this.

Comment: SELECT ``-a.GBPAmt`` FROM TABLE

Comment: Awesome, knew it was going to be simple, was missing the last backtick in the end thanks Ravi, `-a.``GBPAmt```

Comment: backtick for whole column name